# JavaScript api to create and read XSD schema and XML

Tags: javascript, xml, angular, xsd, xml-parsing

Is there any stable api available in JavaScript to generate and read, XSD schema and XML document.

My requirement is:

1. Let one user to define/generate a XSD schema through UI.
2. And later another user will provide appropriate data via UI to create XML accordingly to the XSD created in previous stem.

Please let me if any way to achieve this.

I am building this UI in `Angular` so it would be helpful if its compatible with `Angular`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar use case some time back. I used [jsonix](https://github.com/highsource/jsonix/)

Its conversions are based on declarative XML/JSON mappings which can be written manually or generated from an XML Schema. Hope this helps.